# Make CMake use gccfilter

Tags: gcc, cmake, gccfilter

[GCCFilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/) is a neat perl script that allows to color the output of GCC and thus makes debugging much more fun and, more important, faster.

You can use GCCFilter with a CMake generated Makefile by calling

```
gccfilter -a -c make
```

However, this approach has some drawbacks: Delayed output of CMake status infos, no color in the CMake commands are the most obvious.

The question: Is there a way to write some CMake module that searches for `gccfilter` if the compiler is `gcc`, checks if, say `COLOR_CXX` is set (rather easy up to here) and then tells CMake to replace all calls to `gcc` by `gccfilter -a -c gcc`.

CMake offers the variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, but changing this one will disallow CMake to find correct include paths and the like. Is there some variable we may change after the `project()` command that is prefixed before each call to `gcc`?

Comment: By the way, GCC output should be colorized by default, and if you're running it inside a script, you can use `-fdiagnostics-color-always`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make CMake use `gccfilter` by pointing the [RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_dir:RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE) property to a wrapper script which invokes `gccfilter` with the desired options.

Create an executable shell script named `gccfilter_wrap` in the outermost CMake project directory with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gccfilter -a -c "$@"
```

Be sure to set the file's executable bit. Then in your `CMakeLists.txt`, set the `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` directory property before adding targets:

```
project (HelloWorld)

set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE
   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gccfilter_wrap")

add_executable(HelloWorld HelloWorld.cpp)
```

The generated makefile rules will then prefix each compiler invocation with the `gccfilter_wrap` script. Alternatively the `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` property can also be set as a target property or as global property.

The `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` property only works for Makefile-based CMake generators.

---

### Edit by Thilo

This is how I finally solved the problem - basically a rephrased version of this solution:

```
# GCCFilter, if appliciable
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCPP)
  option(COLOR_GCC "Use GCCFilter to color compiler output messages" ON)
  set(COLOR_GCC_OPTIONS "-c -r -w" CACHE STRING "Arguments that are passed to gccfilter when output coloring is switchend on. Defaults to -c -r -w.")
  if(COLOR_GCC)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/gccfilter ${COLOR_GCC_OPTIONS}")
  endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However, the script is not really necessary, can all be done in CMake. I edited you post to add my final solution - hope you don't mind.

Comment: I tried both versions (wrapper and CMakeLists.txt-only) but each runs into an endless loop when the compilation is almost done (at 99% or 100% progress). Without gccfilter the compilation finishes as expected. Maybe this is related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954237/gccfilter-and-and-gcc-4-7-2-does-not-work-stops-compiling). Any ideas?