# gccfilter and gcc 4.7.2 does not work, stops compiling

Tags: gcc, compilation, gccfilter

I have successfully installed the **gccfilter** (http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/) in my toolchain. The filter should actually work because all perl modules and other stuff has been installed the problem is that it does not work properly  when I use for example the following command line:

```
gccfilter -c -a  g++    -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -I/"tonnes of includes"   -o CMakeFiles/...../main.cpp.o
-c  /...path.../App/main.cpp
.../variant.hpp:17:0,
                 from .../SceneParser.hpp:12,
                 from .../SimulationManager.hpp:12,
                 from .../main.cpp:8:
_ <-- Cursor is here
```

It compiles but after the error message it stops doing anything, the cursor is on the bottom line and nothing happens?
So the tool does not quite work, I am using gcc 4.7.2. i am not quite sure where the problem might be?

Comment: Seem to have the same thing with gcc 4.8.1, wondering if you've solved this-

Comment: @jotrocken It works with me with g++ 4.5.2 on ubuntu.